# How to remove steps from being over the drawer

Tags: css, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, daisyui

I'm using [DaisyUI](https://daisyui.com/) and [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/)

I'm using a [drawer](https://daisyui.com/components/drawer/) and [steps](https://daisyui.com/components/steps/).

```html
<div class="drawer">
    <input id="my-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" />
    <div class="drawer-content">
        <!-- Page content here -->
        <label for="my-drawer" class="btn btn-primary drawer-button">Open drawer</label>
        <ul class="steps">
            <li class="step step-primary">Register</li>
            <li class="step step-primary">Choose plan</li>
            <li class="step">Purchase</li>
            <li class="step">Receive Product</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="drawer-side">
        <label for="my-drawer" class="drawer-overlay" />
        <ul class="menu p-4 w-80 h-full bg-base-200 text-base-content">
            <!-- Sidebar content here -->
            <li><a>Sidebar Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Sidebar Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is the copy/paste from the first example of the drawer and steps component from DaisyUI.

[image]

When I click on *"OPEN DRAWER"* to open the drawer, the circle of the steps remains above it:

[image]

How to make the drawer be over the step circles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps mess with the z-index, which causes issues with the drawer which also relies on this mechanism to draw on top. Would recommend to use [`isolation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation) on the `steps` to restrict the z-index ordering to within that container. (This probably should be part of the `steps` class itself, anyway.)

That way you do not need to know which particular indices are being used.

```html
<ul class="steps isolate">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/daisyui/3.1.7/full.min.css" integrity="sha512-XCyMGudVghtcrEkHUSNd/OvlbxUYXLeI0bYO4jm3Tn1olsupuMnMmRRecHPy0kY/AJI2gc6mTzzCPY5DCsPRCg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="drawer">
  <input id="my-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" />
  <div class="drawer-content">
    <!-- Page content here -->
    <label for="my-drawer" class="btn btn-primary drawer-button">Open drawer</label>
    <ul class="steps isolate">
      <li class="step step-primary">Register</li>
      <li class="step step-primary">Choose plan</li>
      <li class="step">Purchase</li>
      <li class="step">Receive Product</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="drawer-side">
    <label for="my-drawer" class="drawer-overlay"></label>
    <ul class="menu p-4 w-80 h-full bg-base-200 text-base-content">
      <!-- Sidebar content here -->
      <li><a>Sidebar Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sidebar Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider increasing the z-stack position of the `.drawer-side` element by applying `z-index: 10` to it via the `z-10` utility class:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/daisyui/3.1.7/full.min.css" integrity="sha512-XCyMGudVghtcrEkHUSNd/OvlbxUYXLeI0bYO4jm3Tn1olsupuMnMmRRecHPy0kY/AJI2gc6mTzzCPY5DCsPRCg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="drawer">
  <input id="my-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" />
  <div class="drawer-content">
    <!-- Page content here -->
    <label for="my-drawer" class="btn btn-primary drawer-button">Open drawer</label>
    <ul class="steps">
      <li class="step step-primary">Register</li>
      <li class="step step-primary">Choose plan</li>
      <li class="step">Purchase</li>
      <li class="step">Receive Product</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="drawer-side z-10">
    <label for="my-drawer" class="drawer-overlay"></label>
    <ul class="menu p-4 w-80 h-full bg-base-200 text-base-content">
      <!-- Sidebar content here -->
      <li><a>Sidebar Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sidebar Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```